# Fwrite writing twice

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

So I'm currently working on a php script which should be able to download a file and log the command in an xml file called "log.xml".
I'm using the command "fwrite()" but the message being logged is a double of the message I want logged.
Please take a look:

```
function executeCommand($v, $m) {

    if($v == "fetchResult") {
        $filename = "../userFiles/accounts/" . $m . "/log.xml";
        $msg = "<retrieve command='fetchResult' date='" . date("d") . "." . date("m") . "." . date("y") . "' />";
        $file = fopen( $filename, "a+" ); 
            if( $file == false ) { 
                echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
                exit();
            }
            else {
                fwrite($file,$msg . "\n");
            }
        fclose($file);

        $path01 = "../userFiles/accounts/" . $m . "/result.xml";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;'.'filename="result.xml"');
        echo file_get_contents($path01);

    }
}
```

Instead of writing :
`<retrieve command='fetchResult' date='27.07.2016' />`
for instance,
It's writing :
*`<retrieve command='fetchResult' date='27.07.2016' />`*
`<retrieve command='fetchResult' date='27.07.2016' />`
This would lead to a set of errors if I launch my work so please I'll appreciate a lot if you can help.
Thanks :)

Comment: How do you execute `executeCommand`? Will it be used in any sort of loop?

Comment: Be wary if you are writing on an HTTP GET request.  A web browser could be pre-fetching, and this may result in a double write. (e.g. Favicon request, new tab preview etc.)  Check the server access logs.

Comment: `      // Check the value of $cmd
 if($cmd != null) {
  executeCommand($cmd, $matNo);
 }`

Comment: its not really in a loop just as Ive shown above

Comment: and yes, quite right I use the 'get' request @Progrock but hows that a problem? Please explain further; and how can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the web server's access logs as suggested?  If you do get multiple simultaneous (ish) requests it could show there.

Comment: Oh my.... You are right! It's shows twice! How can I resolve that?

Comment: (You can lead a horse to water...)  Identify what the requests are for and where they came from.  Is the URI unique, are other requests being routed through the same endpoint?

Comment: Okay... I think I've just figured it out.. Thanks guys.